# Optimal Fade In and Out of NSView

Tags: macos

I am currently writing a presentation application showing images and video, full screen on multiple monitors. The images and video display one after the other and fade in an out.

At the moment I have this working correct but fades are not smooth, there is a little stutter.
My code currently animates the alpha on each of the components being shown.

```
[[self.videoView animator] setAlphaValue:1.0f];
```

Are there ways of doing this that will improve performance on OSX?

For example, when using cocos2D on iPhone it is more efficient to fade a colour layer up and down over the content, than in is to fade the content itself (i.e. animate the alpha on the most simple component). However, I can't see anything in Cocoa that would allow it to simplify the calculations it is doing (i.e. no simple concept of flat-color layer).

I hope that's clear! Thank you.

Comment: You can also use cocos2d on OS X. It doesn't have to only be for games.

Comment: That's true of course, although for this project a majority of the functionality was easier in Cocoa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making all the NSViews in the hierarchy layer backed makes a huge improvement to the performance of these transitions.

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```